# Can someone show me a simple example of finding simple squared error in k-means?

Tags: reference-request, sums-of-squares, clustering

I'm working on some homework and one of our assignments asks us to find the final mean of each cluster and the SSE (sum of squared error). I haven't been able to find anything online and was wondering if someone could provide an easy example.

Comment: Do you ask for code or explanation? Either way it is sum of squared distance from each cluster assignment.